# SELECT RANGE 1 IN 1 HOUR - POSTGRESQL

Tags: database, postgresql

**GOAL**

I would like to do a `SELECT` within a range of **1 hour in 1 hour**

**DATA TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    t_id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    time   TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, '2019-10-28 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, '2019-10-28 08:30:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, '2019-10-28 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, '2019-10-28 09:30:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, '2019-10-28 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, '2019-10-28 10:30:00');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    t_id,
    MIN(time)
FROM
    t
WHERE
    date_trunc('day', time) = current_date
GROUP BY
    t_id,
    date_trunc('hour', time)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
t_id    min
4   2019-10-28 09:30:00
5   2019-10-28 10:30:00
1   2019-10-28 08:00:00
2   2019-10-28 08:30:00
3   2019-10-28 09:00:00
6   2019-10-28 10:00:00
```

**OUTPUT ESPERADO**

```
t_id    min
1   2019-10-28 08:00:00
3   2019-10-28 09:00:00
5   2019-10-28 10:00:00
```

**NOTE: REFORMED QUESTION**

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fe435/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT ON` to get the first `t_id` per hour.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', time))
t_id, date_trunc('hour', time)
FROM t
WHERE date_trunc('day', time) = current_date
ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', time), t_id;
```

`DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', time))` along with `ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', time), t_id` allows us to grab the lowest t_id for each hour.

If instead you want the very first t_id in order of time, you could do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('hour', time))
t_id, date_trunc('hour', time)
FROM t
WHERE date_trunc('day', time) = current_date
ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', time), time;
```

In this case, they are the same, but in the fiddle you added to the comments, they are not.

Comment: Can you understand where I am going wrong, your answers was perfect friend, thank you for helping me!

Comment: One question, in the case represented here: "http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61eea/1", is the syntax correct?

Comment: Okay, I see, if my table contains two fields, 1 integer for random values and 1 timestamp, can I group by random integers?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by group by the random integers, but you can choose a different way of ordering.  I added a bit more info to my answer.  In the fiddle you added in the comments, if you wanted the first `value` by time for the hour, you would use `ORDER BY date_trunc('hour', clock), clock` http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61eea/5

Comment: I understand, thank you for clarifying all my doubts, have a great week!